# How to create selectable rows from foreach binding?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

KO generates a table via foreach binding:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>First name</th><th>Last name</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: people">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: firstName"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: lastName"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want the rows to be selectable.  In the extremly simply case I can do this with three divs and jQuery.  Note, I need to uniquely identify the row that was clicked.  In this example I do that by reading the ID.

```
<div id="row1">Row 1</div>
<div id="row2">Row 2</div>
<div id="row3">Row 3</div>

$('#row1, #row2, #row3').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('id') + ' clicked');
       $(this).css('background-color','yellow');
});
```

With KO generating my `<tr>` how I can set a unique value for each row?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/smacky311/d9bE6/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a "selected" flag to your items that populate the `<tr>`:

```
ko.applyBindings({
        people: [
            { firstName: 'Bert', lastName: 'Bertington', isSelected: ko.observable(false) },
            { firstName: 'Charles', lastName: 'Charlesforth', isSelected: ko.observable(false) },
            { firstName: 'Denise', lastName: 'Dentiste', isSelected: ko.observable(false) }
        ]
    });
```

Then have your `<tr>` binding use the `isSelected` to apply a css class, as well as the `click` binding to toggle the `isSelected` state (you might not need to toggle -- I just did that for this example):

```
<tr data-bind='css: { selected: isSelected }, click: function() { $data.isSelected(!$data.isSelected()); }'>
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d9bE6/6/).

Comment: I need to know which unique row is selected.  In the real app one of the columns will be used to query the DB.

Comment: If its a property of the object you're binding, you can grab it in the click handler.

Comment: Ah yes I see that in the documentation.  "you need to know which item's UI was clicked": http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a unique value? If all you need to do is highlight a row you can do this. http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/d9bE6/4/

```
$('tr').click(function() {
       $(this).css('background-color','yellow');
});
```

You could set a unique id for each row using an .each() -

```
$('tr').each(function(index) {
    $(this).attr('id', index);
});
```

Comment: I need to know which unique row is selected.  There are multiple tables on the page.  Not all of them are selectable.

Comment: Ah...ok. You had asked about setting a unique value for each row, I didn't know you needed to know which were selected.

Comment: I do only need a unique value.  I do not need multiple selections.  The only issue I see with this answer is that it marks all tr's on the page.  I only track some of them.

Comment: You would have to narrow this down for the table rows that you want to id. Or you could calculate the index value of the row on-th-fly and use that.